# Find The Curvature of the given curve

Tags: differential-geometry

Find the curvature of the curve :
$ x = t - \sin{t} $ , $y = 1 - \cos{t} $ , $z=4\sin{\dfrac{t}{2}}$.

I have been trying to find the curvature using the formula 
$ {k_{1}}^2 = \dfrac{{\begin{vmatrix} x''& y'' \\ x' & y' \end{vmatrix}}^2 +{\begin{vmatrix} y'' & z'' \\ y' & z' \end{vmatrix}}^2 + {\begin{vmatrix} z'' & x'' \\ z' & x' \end{vmatrix}}^2}{({x'}^{2}+{y'}^{2}+{z'}^{2})^3}.$

Comment: What have you try? Thanks!

Comment: I was using the direct formula for the curvature given in the book A. Pogorelov Geometry, but not able to find precise answer. Shall I attach the image of my work, Sir?

Comment: Try to apply the formula of the book and write done what you did!

Comment: I have added the formula Sir. It seems the answer is straight. But I'm lost in calculation.

Comment: You have the formula already, so just plug in the expressions for $x, y, z$ and simplify (and just leave that as answer).